# replace log4j with slf4j in hybris

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, sap-commerce-cloud

I am wandering if there is an elegant way to change logging in hybris from log4j to slf4j or something else?

Right now I am using slf4j when writing java code, but hybris itself is using log4j for any generated code. That is causing to use mixed logging frameworks in one hybris extension.
Actually it is still log4j underneath the slf4j, but what if I want to change log4j to some other logging mechanism?

Maybe it can be done in some configuration file. Has anybody done that already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your current configuration, you can use a bridge between log4j and slf4j.<sup>**1**</sup>

[image: Image from http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html]

In this way, you wouldn't need to modify the generated code. You can use a similar configuration if you use Log4J 2 as underlying logging framework.

See also [*Bridging legacy APIs*](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) in [**www.slf4j.org**](http://www.slf4j.org/).

---

*Notes*

1. Assuming you do not use log4j as underlying logging framework. Otherwise, this would result in an error stack.
2. Image from http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this should do the trick. What about Hybris? Would it digest those changes easy or would it have some stomach problems with it? I can't try it with Hybris right now, but I wonder if anybody else did try this?

Comment: I think that with this configuration should to work. You only need to use Log4J 2 or logback as underlying logging framework.